# OpenMP, multithreaded BFS, ptr to C array as locals

Tags: arrays, c, multithreading, openmp

I'm working on an implementation of multithreaded BFS in C. I watched a video called "High Level Approach to Parallel BFS" where the explanation said that I wanna multithread each "level" in the path.

```c
// Parameters:
// n     : number of vertices
// ver   : array of length n. ver[i] points to the start of the neighbor list of vertex i in edges
// edges : array containing lists of neighbors for each vertex, each edge is listed in both direction
// p     : array of length n used for parent pointers
// dist  : array of length n used for distance from starting vertex
// S     : array of length n used for maintaining queue of vertices to be processed
// T     : array of length n where n >> number of threads.
//
// Note that the vertices are numbered from 1 to n (inclusive). Thus there is
// no vertex 0.

void pbfs(int n, int* ver, int* edges, int* p, int* dist, int* S, int* T)
{
    int i, j;          // Loop indices
    int v, w;          // Pointers to vertices
    int num_r, num_w;  // Number of vertices in S and T, respectively
    int* temp;        // Temporary pointer

#pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {   // Set that every node is unvisited
        p[i] = -1;          // Using -1 to mark that a vertex is unvisited
        dist[i] = -1;
    }

    p[1] = 1;        // Set the parent of starting vertex to itself
    dist[1] = 0;     // Set the distance from the starting vertex to itself
    S[0] = 1;        // Add the starting vertex to S

    num_r = 1;       // Number of vertices in S
    num_w = 0;       // Number of vertices in T


#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(T)
    {
        while (num_r != 0) {                            // Loop until all vertices have been discovered
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait
            for (i = 0; i < num_r; i++) {               // Loop over vertices in S
                v = S[i];                               // Grab next vertex v in S
                for (j = ver[v]; j < ver[v + 1]; j++) { // Go through the neighbors of v
                    w = edges[j];                       // Get next neighbor w of v

                    if (p[w] == -1) {                   // Check if w is undiscovered
                        p[w] = v;                       // Set v as the parent of w
                        dist[w] = dist[v] + 1;          // Set distance of w
                        T[num_w++] = w;                 // Add w to T and increase number of vertices 
                    }
                }       // End loop over neighbors of v
            }           // End loop of vertices in S
            temp = S;   // Swap S and T
            S = T;
            T = temp;
            num_r = num_w; // Set number of elements in S
            num_w = 0;     // Set T as empty
        } //  End loop over entire graph
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that multithreading the first for loop after the while would accomplish what I want, but comes with the problems the if statement. I was thinking that this could be solved by making the two first writes to p and dist atomic and making T local to each thread.

I'm wondering if this plan works? And I'm wondering what would happen if I did as below. Does each thread get their own ptr to the same C array? If that's the case I'm still gonna have issues.

Comment: Your scheme may work. However, if the tree is unbalanced you may have lots of overhead from the dynamic scheduling. Consider using tasks, which really express the parallelism in the tree.

Comment: Unfortunately your code has many problems:  practically all of your variables are shared (`j, v, w, num_r, num_w, temp`, etc ) and they cause data race. You should first fix it and my suggestion is to define your variables at their minimum required scope (it can solve some of the problems). Regarding `w` and if statement: the question is that different `i`  can give the same `w`? If so, there is also a data race, which have to be resolved as well using atomic operations (reads and writes as well). Line `T[num_w++] = w;` also can cause problems...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple synchronization issues.

**Issue 1**:
You NEED a synchronization after a "level" in BFS and hence after the `for` loop. The `nowait` has to be removed to allow synchronization. Otherwise, all the threads may end up executing the code after the `for` loop, and completely distort the concept of "level", and making the rest of the code problematic.

**Issue 2**:
You cannot make `T` private, because it is a shared data structure to store the active nodes for the next "level". Hence, all of the parallel threads should be writing to the same `T`. You do not need atomic writing to `T` however, just the atomic increment of `num_w`.

It is ok update the `dist` variable non-atomically, because in a BFS, the `dist[v] + 1` of all the v on the same "level" is the same.

Technically, you do not need `p` variable to store the parent node (well there can be multiple parents), you just want to make sure that the `dist[w]` is not written earlier in a previous "level". So, it is just a flag to indicate that status, and can be simply set to something other than `-1` while writing.

In other words, you just have to make the increment of `num_w` atomic, and the rest of the assignments in the `if` block can be kept as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I'll try to implement this! I believe I can make these variables atomic with omp read/write/update according to https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbclx01/prag_omp_atomic.htm

Comment: Wouldn't making num_w atomic be bad? Wouldn't be much different then sequential because every single thread visits num_w and will wait for it to be available?

Comment: @MegaMagnum Running `T[num_w++] = w;` in parallel (using atomic increase of `num_w`) will give the same array elements, but in a different order compared to serial code. I do not know your algorithm to decide if it is a problem or not.

Comment: Atomic update of num_w could indeed be a performance bottleneck. If you keep `T` private, you need to find a way to combine the private `T`s to form the `S` (in a parallel way) before starting the next `for` loop. 

Be aware that there are other performance bottlenecks as well. Eg., launching an openmp thread incurs significant overhead, which may not be worth it if the vertices typically have very few neighbors.

Comment: The synchronization after the for loop is also costly. The performance is very graph-structure dependent, and can easily end up worse than the sequential execution.